# Navigation is not working with struts 2

Tags: java, struts2

I have called struts action through json like this

```
function(){ 
    var data = {};
    data['userLogin.userName'] = $('#username').val().trim();
    data['userLogin.password']  = $('#password').val().trim();


    $.ajax({url:'loginAction', 
        cache: false,
        data:data, 
        dataType: 'json'
        });     
};
```

.

this is my struct action mapping code segment

```
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">



    <struts>

    <constant name="struts.objectFactory" value="org.apache.struts2.spring.StrutsSpringObjectFactory"/>

    <!-- Configuration for the default package. -->
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default,json-default">



      <action name="loginAction" class="loginAction" method="doLogin">
            <result name="success">/test.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">/index.jsp</result>
      </action>
    </package>



</struts>
```

and this is my spring configuration file data

```
<bean id="loginDAO" class="com.mls.dao.LoginDAOImpl"></bean>

<bean id="loginService" class="com.mls.service.LoginServiceImpl">
    <property name="loginDAO" ref="loginDAO"></property>
</bean> 

<bean id="loginAction" class="com.mls.action.LoginAction">
    <property name="loginService" ref="loginService"></property>
</bean>
```

loginSerice return success but navigation is not working. Give me idea how to fix this?

Comment: Read this http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/.

Comment: i think, nothing wrong with ajex calling. when login button click service method call and get username and password through json. Struts action class return success but according to action mapping in struts.xml file it should navigate to test.jsp page. but this navigation is not working. :(

Comment: check out, if both parameter all reached your action class. check out, if your dependency correctly injected. or you have to post your action class, your configurations look fine

Answer (score 1):

It is ajax request. If you want to redirect to some other url you must do that in javascript. Read http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp and http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/.